# gdal_calc.py raster reclass equivalent of ArcGIS reclass or r.reclass in grass

Tags: python, gdal

Would like to achieve this in gdal_calc.Py if possible.

I have a raster with a value of 0-7 in GTiff

I would like one output raster where

NoData = 0,1,2,3

1 = 4,5,6,7

So basically an ArcGIS reclass but using gdal_calc.py. I know how to do it in QGIS, ArcGIS, etc.

I know this question has been asked before for SAGA, QGIS, GRASS (r.reclass), but I do not see it for gdal_calc.py

Comment: gdal_calc.py -A Aq.tiff --outfile=Aq_Reclass.tiff --calc="A*(A>3)" --NoDataValue=0  This seems to work for the NoData part , setting 0,1,2,3 to NoData but how to set 4,5,6,7 to 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help

this seems to work.

gdal_calc.py -A *filename*.tiff --outfile=*filename*.tiff --calc="A*(A>3)" --NoDataValue=0 --calc="1*(A<3)

Comment: not exactly, but this is the right track. You could use --calc="1*(A>3)" (note that 1* is not necessary here, just for the example).

Comment: `--calc` shouldn't be passed twice - I believe the first will be ignored.

Comment: you have to make a single 
--calc                                                                          
1*(A<=4) +2*((A>4)*(A<=9))+3*((A>9)*(A<=16))+4*((A>16)*(A<=31))+5*((A>31)*(A<=41))+6*((A>41)*(A<=1000))

Comment: The answer has 2 `--calc` expressions, which is accepted by `gdal_calc.py` (if the GDAL version >= 3.2). However in this case it seems to be a mistake. Multiple `--calc` expressions should be used only to produce a multiband file: https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_calc.html#cmdoption-calc