# Can GDAL fill elevation below a certain value?

Tags: qgis, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I have several GeoTIFFs that I'm working with to create contours using gdal_contour. One of them crashes the utility. gdalinfo tells me that the computed min values for band 1 and 2 are -340282346638528860000000000000000000000...  This seems to be creating the problem as none of the others are so irrational (think in the single digit range / near sea-level).

Is there a way to "fix" this geotiff by replacing anything below 0 with a reasonable value such as 1 or even 0? And can I simultaneously replace "nodata" values with 0 or 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gdal_Calc.py can do that, a reclass

Something like..

gdal_calc.py -A filename.tiff --outfile=filename.tiff
--calc="A*(A>3)" --NoDataValue=0 --calc="1*(A<3)

See this one

[gdal_calc.py raster reclass equivalent of ArcGIS reclass or r.reclass in grass](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/100348/gdal-calc-py-raster-reclass-equivalent-of-arcgis-reclass-or-r-reclass-in-grass)

Comment: Thanks! Got it to work with: gdal_calc.py -A filename.tiff --outfile=filename.tiff --calc="A*(A>3)" --NoDataValue=0     (what is the second --calc attribute for? I didn't end up using it)

Comment: is is just a sample, it changes the other values to 1

Answer (score 2):

If the min value is consistent - like a no data value, you might be able to use the snodata option and specify the value you want ignore. As listed in the doc for [gdal_contour](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_contour.html)